# Intercepting IIS 7.0 Http requests without HttpModule (and not ISAPI)

Tags: http, iis-7, httprequest, servermanager

I am working on a project that is based on the ability to 'intercept' incoming HTTP requests in IIS 7.0.
I only need some basic information on what URL's are being requested within IIS at the current moment, for further processing.

Is there a way to achieve that without an HttpModule ? Like, hook into IIS 'global' process somehow ?
I mean, I would like to create a product, that would not require registering an HttpModule in the GAC, or having website owners to include any configuration details (or even do anything) within his web application (web.config), etc..

The information I need is mainly the URL being requested, but also I might need IIS application ID, in order to determine site's location on the hard drive and create some folder in there...

**Some additional explanation to make my question clearer**:

I am talking about an application (a server-side component) on a 'server-wide' scale, so, that any particular 'site' owner (while there could be multiple sites hosted under our IIS7 instance) would not have to do anything on his part, yet my "server-side" component would know that a URL was requested on one of those sites...

For example, basically my "Component" will receive a message that a url "/about-us"/ was requested on a site with host name "one-of-my-hosted-domains.com" without having to do anything (no global.asax, no web.config, or throwing an HttpModule into the BIN or GAC..) - I need some completely seamless way of knowing what URLs are being requested on my local instance of IIS... (as if it would be an HttpModule sitting on that domain... :)

I would be very grateful for some hints on this!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler approach would suffice; turn on request logging for your IIS server, then monitor the resulting log files.  You should see an entry for each request.